# Tuple literals in interface declarations

Tags: c#, interface, tuples

So yay for Tuples! I know I can return multiple values from a method with tuples and name them so they don't have to be Item1, Item2, etc. 
I can go `var results = (result1: r1, result2: r2);`

But how do you use tuple literals in an interface declaration such as this?

```
public interface IFoo {
    (T1, T2) Bar();
}
```

Tried doing `(result1: T1, result2: t2) Bar();` but it doesn't work. Is there a way of returning a named tuple from an interface method?

Comment: What is `T1` and `T2`? `public interface IFoo<T1, T2>` and you are ok.

Comment: *"but it doesn't work."* When you leave details like *how* it didn't work (e.g., exception details, compiler errors) it makes it harder for us to help. Also, looks like you're trying to use generics without defining the generic type variables.  `public interface IFoo<T1, T2> { }`

Comment: @IvanStoev If you add that as an answer, I'll upvote it. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax for named tuples as a method return type is incorrect:

```
public interface IFoo {
    (T1 result1, T2 result2) Bar();
}
```

Note: This is because your return type defines the type and name, while assigning names of a tuple literal defines the value and name.

```
// Method return syntax. Type & Name
public (bool success, T payload) TryGetPayload<T>() { }

// Literal assignment syntax. Name & Value
var result = (success: true, payload: t);
```

Comment: So remove the colons then?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "literals" to any interface like that, unless as return *values* for concrete methods.

You can, however, use types. If your T1 and T2 are meant to be generic, you can use Ivan Stoev's comment on the question:

```
public interface IFoo<T1, T2> {
    (T1, T2) Bar();
}
```

If your T1 and T2 are meant to be concrete, you can use them directly, as mentioned in Neil's answer:

```
public interface IFoo<T1, T2> {
    (int, string) Bar();
}
```

You can also name them, if you want:

```
public interface IFoo<T1, T2> {
    (T1 theLeft, T2 theRight) Bar();
}
```

or

```
public interface IFoo<T1, T2> {
    (int theNumber, string theName) Bar();
}
```